# programar en JAVA con un mac, problema con JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, macos

estoy empezando con Java en mi mac y tengo un error que no consigo solucionar al crear 2 JTextField. Al pulsar con el ratón o asignarle el foco crea un bucle en el cual no para de cambiar de JTextField dicho foco. Les adjunto el código:

```
package appGraficas;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class EventosFoco {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MarcoFoco marco = new MarcoFoco();
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

}


class MarcoFoco extends JFrame {

    public MarcoFoco() {
        setTitle("Primer ejercicio con focus");
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        add(new LaminaFoco());
    }

}

class LaminaFoco extends JPanel {

    JTextField cuadroUno = new JTextField();
    JTextField cuadroDos = new JTextField();

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        setLayout(null); 
        cuadroUno.setBounds(150, 10, 100, 20);
        cuadroDos.setBounds(150, 50, 100, 20);
        cuadroUno.grabFocus();
        add(cuadroUno);
        add(cuadroDos);
        LanzaFocus foco = new LanzaFocus();
        cuadroUno.addFocusListener(foco);
    }

    private class LanzaFocus implements FocusListener {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("foco ganado");
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método *paintComponent* no es donde debes inicializar el componente. Este método es llamado continuamente para volver a pintar el componente, y se implementa si por alguna razón tienes que pintar "a mano" el contenido del componente (en lugar de dejar que el JPanel pinte los componentes hijos).

Así, cada vez que Java invoca el *paintComponent*, vuelves a añadir los dos JTextField(), y *añades una nueva instancia de LanzaFocus* a los listeners.

Convierte *paintComponent* en un constructor para *LaminaFoco*.

Comment: Entonces la mejor manera seria crear un constructor para la clase y crearlo en el constructor sin usar el método _paintComponent_ ??

Comment: Por ejemplo. Lo importante es que tu código solo tiene que ejecutarse una vez por cada instancia de *LaminaFoco* que crees, y el constructor es la solución más natural.